# Linear algebra done right 7.C.11

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, orthonormal, isometry

> Suppose $T_1, T_2$ are normal operators on $\mathcal L(\mathbb{F}^3)$ and both operators have $2, 5, 7$ as eigenvalues. Prove that there exists an isometry $S\in \mathcal L(\mathbb{F}^3)$ such that $T_1 = S^*T_2S$

I don't know how to approach this problem and
Question: If $T_1, T_2$ have the same eigenvalues, does it mean their matrix representation is the same w.r.t the same orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{F}^3$.

Comment: I would say no, but I'm not too confident in this. You can maybe think about a relation (call two matrices of the same size related if they have the same eigenvalues), but I'm not too sure about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the matrix representation of two operators with respect to some basis is the same, then the operators are equal and this doesn't have to be the case, even in your situation.

In your case, call the distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$. Since $T_1$ has distinct eigenvalues, it is diagonalizable. Since $T_1$ is normal, you can choose an **orthonormal** basis $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ of $\mathbb{F}^3$ consisting of eigenvectors of $T_1$ (with $T_1v_i = \lambda_i v_i$). The same argument applies to $T_2$ resulting in an orthonormal basis $(w_1,w_2,w_3)$ of eigenvectors of $T_2$ (with $T_2 w_i = \lambda_i w_i$). Define an operator $S \colon \mathbb{F}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^3$ by $S(v_i) = w_i$. Since $S$ sends an orthonormal basis to an orthonormal basis, the map $S$ is an isometry and we have

$$ (S^{*}T_2S)(v_i) = S^{*}T(w_i) = S^{*}(\lambda_i w_i) = \lambda_i S^{-1}(w_i) = \lambda_i v_i = T_1(v_i) $$

and so $T_1 = S^{*}T_2S$.

Comment: Thanks, can I ask how do you come up with the idea to define S map like the way you did?

Comment: The equation $T_1 = S^{*} T_2 S$ when $S$ is an isometry tells you that $T_1$ and $T_2$ are orthogonally similar - that is, $T_1$ and $T_2$ act "the same way" on your space up to an isometry. Since $T_i$ have the same distinct eigenvalues, we know how they act on the eigenvectors and so we see that they act the same way on your space up to "rotating" one orthonormal basis to another.

Comment: @levap Wouldn't this only work for F=C, since if F=R, T normal doesn't mean you can choose an ONB consisting of eigenvectors?

Comment: @Larry: True, a normal operator on $\mathbb{R}$ is not necessarily diagonalizable. However, the argument still works because you are **given** that $T_1,T_2$ have three distinct (and real) eigenvalues, hence a basis of eigenvectors and since $T_1,T_2$ are normal, eigenvectors associated to different eigenvalues are orthogonal to each other and so you can normalize them and obtain and orthonormal basis of eigenvectors.